# Oracle SQL Regex not returning expected results

Tags: regex, oracle

I am using a regex that works perfectly in Java/PHP/regex testers.

```
\d(?:[()\s#-]*\d){3,}
```

Examples: https://regex101.com/r/oH6jV0/1

However, trying to use the same regex in Oracle SQL is returning no results. Take for example:

```
select *
from
(select column_value str from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('123','1234','12345','12 135', '1', '12 3')))
where regexp_like(str, '\d(?:[()\s#-]*\d){3,}');
```

This returns no rows. Why does this act so differently? I even used a regex tester that does POSIX ERE, but that still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle does not support non-capturing groups `(?:)`. You will need to use a capturing group instead.

It also doesn't like the perl-style whitespace meta-character `\s` match inside a character class `[]` (it will match the characters `\` and `s` instead of whitespace). You will need to use the POSIX expression `[:space:]` instead.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/6169)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from (
  select column_value str
  from   table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('123','1234','12345','12 135', '1', '12 3'))
)
where regexp_like(str, '\d([()[:space:]#-]*\d){3,}')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/6169/0)**:

```
|    STR |
|--------|
|   1234 |
|  12345 |
| 12 135 |
```

Comment: Cool. This seems mostly right (for what it is), but it's not matching spaces e.g. '12 135'.

Comment: @Jeremy Updated - swap perl `\s` for POSIX `[:space:]` inside the character class (as others have already mentioned).